# Express return empty EJS values from button name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

TLDR: I'm trying to get the name value of a button using express (ex body parser module) but idk why the code returns an empty string in the name property of my button.

Long explanation: Im generating 2 different lists for a todo list app, so I'm trying to use the listTitle ejs value to send the new tasks to the correct list, as the value returns an empty string they are all posted on the same list. What confuses me the most is that in the h1 of the page the ejs tag works perfectly.

**Here's my server code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

let items = [];
let workItems = [];

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  let day = date.getDate();

  res.render("list", {
    listTitle: day,
    newListItems: items,
  });
});

app.get("/work", function (req, res) {
  res.render("list", { listTitle: "Work", newListItems: workItems });
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  var item = req.body.newItem;
  console.log(req.body);

  if (req.body.list === "Work") {
    workItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");
  } else {
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen("3000", function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**And here is my frontend:**

```
<%- include('header'); -%> 

    <div class="box" id="heading">
      <h1><%= listTitle %></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
          <% for ( var i=0; i<newListItems.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p><%= newListItems[i] %></p>
      </div>
      <% } %>

 
    <form class="item" action="/" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New task" autocomplete="off" />
      <button type="submit" name="name" value="<% listTitle %>">+</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  </body>

<%- include('footer'); -%>
```

Im also including my other js module to import the date just in case this is the problem.

```
exports.getDate = function () {
  const today = new Date();

  const options = {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long",
  };

  return today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
};

exports.getDay = function () {
  const today = new Date();

  const options = {
    weekday: "long",
  };

  return today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
};
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `=` in your `<% listTitle %>`? Shouldn't it be `<%= listTitle %>` (similar to your `h1`)?

Comment: You are right on that but it didnt solve my issue :(

Comment: Is the `<%= listTitle %>` value that you want to send to backend for the `POST`?

Comment: Yes, I want that value to be sent to the backend so I can disclose which list is the user posting on and push the new tasks into the correct array. The change you proposed I think is the correct approach as now Node returns the correct list name but it is still pushing the new tasks into the wrong list.

Comment: In the `app.post("/" ..` you're calling `var item = req.body.newItem;` .. that means whatever value inside the ` <input type="text" name="newItem"  .. ` in the frontend are suppose to be the value for `var item ..` so, are you really trying to get `<%= listTitle %>` as the value for `var item =...` or are you trying to use `<%= listTitle %>` as parameters?

Comment: Thanks for  your reply! It made me realize that I needed to change the name of the button to list (seems I forget to do it at some point). As you said, I'm trying to use that listTitle to let the backend calculate at which list should the new input be saved.

The var item = req,body.newItem is to define the item value with the new task the user has input.